# RegEx for matching a pattern with multiple fixed boundaries in Sublime

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out how to create an expression for Sublime that can find in files when a variable (m_CastShadows) is 1 through 3 for a given sub-section of text (ParticleSystemRenderer:), but ignore that same variable name if it is in a different section (MeshRenderer:).

Each section begins with "--- !".

How would I find sections that begin with "ParticleSystemRenderer:" and includes `m_CastShadow: [1-3]`?

In the below example text, the first "ParticleSystemRenderer:" block would be skipped, because "m_CastShadows" is 0, while the second would be matched, because "m_CastShadows" is 2.

My question is: What would be the expression to have Sublime return files where ONLY the "m_CastShadows" variable in any "ParticleSystemRenderer:" section of the file that is not zero and ignoring any other "m_CastShadows" variable it finds in other sections?

I tried the following expression to return all files that contain this string using the expression `m_CastShadows: [1-3]` but that will return files where ANY "m_CastShadows" is not zero (not just the "ParticleSystemRenderer:" section ones).

Beyond that though I'm pretty lost with RegEx. I did try to build an expression at regexr.com, but could not figure out a working expression for this.

EXAMPLE TEXT:

```
--- !u!1 &75000372733
MeshRenderer:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 1
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 100100000}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 1000010438045922}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_CastShadows: 1
  m_ReceiveShadows: 1
  m_DynamicOccludee: 1
  m_MotionVectors: 1
--- !u!23 &23000010372327926
ParticleSystemRenderer:
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_CastShadows: 0
  m_ReceiveShadows: 0
  m_DynamicOccludee: 1
  m_MotionVectors: 1
--- !u!2 &23006841372327911
SomeOtherSection:
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_CastShadows: 1
  m_ReceiveShadows: 0
--- !u!23 &97320010372327543
ParticleSystemRenderer:
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_CastShadows: 2
  m_ReceiveShadows: 0
  m_DynamicOccludee: 1
  m_MotionVectors: 1
--- !u!2 &23006841372327911
SomeOtherSection2:
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_CastShadows: 3
  m_ReceiveShadows: 0
```

With the above example text I would expect Sublime to return the file if the "m_CastShadows" for ONLY the "ParticleSystemRenderer:" section is greater than 0. It would ignore the one in "MeshRenderer:" regardless of its value.

It would also not return the file if "m_CastShadows" for the "ParticleSystemRenderer:" section was changed to zero (again, regardless of what the one in the "MeshRenderer:" section was set to - or any other section of the file that happened to use the same variable name).

It is also worth noting that the file may contain multiple "ParticleSystemRenderer:" sections. As long as one of the "m_CastShadows" variables in one of those "ParticleSystemRenderer:" sections is greater than zero, I would want it to return the file.

Thanks in advance to you RegEx wizards for guidance in this!

Comment: What separates sections ? Where does it begin and end ?

Comment: A new section seems to begin with "--- !".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for your specific example

```
(?:\r?\n|^)ParticleSystemRenderer:.*\r?\n(?:[ ]{2,}.*\r?\n)*?[ ]{2,}m_CastShadows:[ ]*([1-9]\d*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/GVSWuZ/1

If your engine supports multi-line mode, use this

```
(?m)^ParticleSystemRenderer:.*\s*(?:^[ ]{2,}.*\s*)*?[ ]{2,}m_CastShadows:[ ]*([1-9]\d*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/wLmlAL/1

Comment: This did the trick, thank you! Sublime used the multi-line version fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/6vvmHS/1) might help you to design one:

```
(ParticleSystemRenderer:[\s\S]*)(m_CastShadows: [1-3])
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how it works:

[image]

- You can add additional boundaries to it, if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This was close, but wasn't quite what was needed however. I since clarified the question and example text further to better explain as I was struggling to fully explain what criteria was needed.

While the match starts with "ParticleSystemRender:" line, the match carries though into other blocks below to the last valid "m_CastShadows" line. I'm looking to end or abort the match if it enters a new section beginning with "--- !"

I really appreciate the reply though!